# Conditional OnClick With Razor in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a variable named wURL which contains a URL.  If the URL is NULL I would like to not have the onclick Event in my TD.  My trouble is figuring out how to do this in razor syntax:

```
<td class="" onclick="window.open('@wURL', '_blank')">
```

I'm thinking it should be something like this:

```
<td class="" (@wURL ?){ onclick="window.open('@wURL', '_blank')"}>
```

But This doesn't work.  What is the correct way to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td @(Html.Raw(wURL == null ? "" : $"onclick=\"window.open('{wURL}', '_blank')\"")) >
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but it takes my wURL and breaks the URL up on every / forwardslash, and also breaks up on spaces

Comment: @JoeStellato Updated my answer. Please check

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

I'll leave this here for those who want to display different elements switch a condition with razor :

```
@if(condition){
    <td onclick="window.open('@wURL','_blank')">...</td>
}
else{
    <td >...</td>
}
```

However, if you want only a part of it to be different, then you'll find the other answers more suitable.

Comment: I've tried this, but Razor is having a hard time finding the closing </td>, so I'd rather stick to it in the inline method

Comment: Mmh you're right, this works when you have self-closing tags like `<a [...]/>` or if you want to have completely different TDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
@{string oc = wURL == null ? "" : "onclick=window.open('" + @wURL + "','_blank')";}
<td class = "" @oc>
```

At request of questioner I'll break down the ternary into a simpler if-else statement for clarification:

```
@{ // start a c# block
    string oc; // create a string variable
    if wURL == null { //before I used a "ternary" conditional, but this compiles to the same thing
        oc = ""; // if wURL is null set oc to empty string, so nothing will be written in the tag 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        oc = "onclick=window.open('" + @wURL + "','_blank')"; // set the onclick to open a window with the wURL variable
    }
}
<td class = "" @oc> 
<!-- If the oc variable is empty, nothing will be written after class modifier, otherwise you'll get the onclick statement -->
```

To see how the if-else statement can be compacted into the ternary in the original example look [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ternary).

Comment: Could you explain the answer?

Comment: Yes. I'll break it down into smaller parts

Comment: I've turned the ternary conditional into a clearer if-else statement so you can see how it works.